# Xamarin: iOS won't send punctuation in strings to a web endpoint

Tags: c#, ios, json, http, servicestack

Pretty strange issue, I'm using ServiceStack as a web API and I have a standard endpoint set up that I should be able to post a string to. However, on my iOS devices I can't send strings with any punctuations. Some will just crash the app completely, others such as the question mark will cut off all text after it.

Here's an example, I have an endpoint set up that resembles this

```
    public class FeedbackDTO
    {
        public bool postResult { get; set; }
    }

    [Route("/feedback", "POST")]
    [Route("/feedback/{uuid}/{content}", "POST")]
    public class GiveFeedback : IReturn<FeedbackDTO>
    {
        public string Uuid { get; set; }
        public string Content { get; set; }
    }
```

So if I post to the endpoint I will just save it to the database like so

```
            await Commons.MobileService.GetTable<Feedback>().InsertAsync(new Feedback
            {
                Uuid = uuid,
                Content = content,
                Date = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow
            });
            return true;
```

Now using just a basic client such as Postman to make Http requests I can send a request that will look like `'.../api/feedback?Uuid=something&Content=Will this work? Lets see"` Using Postman or another client this will work fine, but in my Xamarin code when I post it like so

```
        return (await JsonWebService.PostAsync(new GiveFeedback
        {
            Uuid = myUuid,
            Content = "Will this work? Lets see"
        })).postResult;
```

Everything after the `?` will be cut off, so the only thing that is saved to the database is `Will this work`. Pretty strange issue because regular http request clients will send the entire string, but my particular JSON poster I'm using in Xamarin seems to cut everything off after particular punctuation points.

Any ideas why this is occurring?

If it helps, the client I am using in Xamarin is the `ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing a POST you definitely don't want to make the Content you're sending as part of your Route - the url should only be used to identify the resource whilst any Content should only be sent in the Request body.

To do this just remove the inappropriate route entirely:

```
[Route("/feedback", "POST")]
public class GiveFeedback : IReturn<FeedbackDTO>
{
    public string Uuid { get; set; }
    public string Content { get; set; }
}
```

Then any remaining properties not defined on the Route are POST'ed as Form Data.

Answer (score 1):

Even though it's a POST method, your Route contains uuid and content. Hence the uuid and content should be url encoded I believe.

```
[Route("/feedback", "POST")]
[Route("/feedback/{uuid}/{content}", "POST")] // I'm talking about this
```

Try url encoding the two fields.

It's working with postman because it must be handling url encoding for you.